# Realm query with List

Tags: android, realm

I'm using realm to store my data on Android. Awesome framework! Now the only problem I'm now having is:

I got a array list strings with id's of Countries in my database.

Now I retrieve my Drinks that contains a relationship to countries.

Is there a way that I could to do a query like this:

```
String [] ids;

realm.where(Drinks.class).equalsTo("country.id", ids);
```

Something like that?

Or do I really need to do a query to get me all drinks and then filter the list manually?

EDIT:

My classes:

```
public class Drinks extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Country country;
}

public class Country extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: I would need to see your Drinks class and your Country class to tell you the answer.

Comment: edited my question :-)

Comment: In that case, yes, the hypothetical query you mentioned would indeed work, it's described in the "LINK QUERIES" section of the docs. https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries although I personally find that link queries are kinda slow, when I set the `country` in Realm I also set a field called `countryId` so that I don't need to use link queries - but that's just me.

Comment: but neither contains or equalsTo takes an array as second parameter?

Comment: ...oh, that's what you meant.

Comment: I asked the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33651585/4034572). My solution does return an empty `RealmResults<>` if the list of ids is empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want to do is possible with link queries in theory (searching for `"country.id"`), however link queries are slow. Also you'd need to concatenate a bunch of `or()` predicates together, and I would not risk that with a link query.

I would recommend using the following

```
public class Drinks extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Country country;
    @Index
    private String countryId;
}

public class Country extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

And when you set the `Country` in your class, you also set the `countryId` as `country.getId()`.

Once you do that, you can construct such:

```
RealmQuery<Drinks> drinkQuery = realm.where(Drinks.class);
int i = 0;
for(String id : ids) {
    if(i != 0) {
        drinkQuery = drinkQuery.or();
    }
    drinkQuery = drinkQuery.equalTo("countryId", id);
    i++;
}
return drinkQuery.findAll();
```

Comment: The lack of fundamental things like an IN operator, is extremely concerning and inconvenient.

Comment: @RunLoop honestly, you can make an IN operator with barely 5 lines. If you want to nitpick, talk about the lack of primitive RealmLists.

Comment: Realm 1.2.0 added `in()` operator for `RealmQuery`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: can you help in this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936344/print-realm-query-android?noredirect=1#comment86888280_49936344)

Answer (score 8):

Since the Realm database has added `RealmQuery.in()` with the version [1.2.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#120)

I suggest using something like this.

```
//Drinks
public class Drinks extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
private String id;
private String name;
private String countryId;

//getter and setter methods
}

//Country
public class Country extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name;

//getter and setter methods
}
```

The code to use inside activity/fragments to retrieve drink list

```
String[] countryIdArray = new String[] {"1","2","3"} //your string array
RealmQuery<Drinks> realmQuery  = realm.where(Drinks.class)
            .in("countryId",countryIdArray);
RealmResults<Drinks> drinkList = realmQuery.findAll();
```

Comment: Take care to use .in with kotlin with backticks

Answer (score 1):

In latest version of Realm **7+**, you can use `anyOf` to match a field against a list of values.

```
anyOf("name", new String[]{"Jill", "William", "Trillian"})
```

in older versions, use `in` instead of `anyOf` and with kotlin use `oneOf` instead of `in`.

see [this issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4092#issuecomment-348572935)

Answer (score 0):

To match a field against a list of values, use in. For example, to find the names “Jill,” “William,” or “Trillian”, you can use in("name", new String[]{"Jill", "William", "Trillian"}). The in predicate is applicable to strings, binary data, and numeric fields (including dates).

Doc.-> https://realm.io/docs/java/latest#queries