# Clause IN Realm Java

Tags: java, android, realm

I have been reading Realm Java documentation and I couldn't find 
something like clause "IN" in SQL, somebody maybe have worked with something similar?. Currently I'm using a loop to bring results one by one, but I don't want to do that.

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: IN is currently not supported, but we have an issue tracking it here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/841 . For now the solution is creating the query in a loop.

Comment: It's really easy,  look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32068221/2413303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm has supported the `in` clause for some time, but wasn't officially documented until 3.1.3.  It works for use with Strings, numeric fields, dates and binary data.

Example Usage with Strings:

```
realm.where(Person.class)
     .in("name", new String[]{"Jill", "William", "Trillian"})
     .findAll();
```

Or optionally you can ignore case..

```
realm.where(Person.class)
     .in("name", new String[]{"Jill"}, Case.INSENSITIVE)
     .findAll();
```

See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#filtering for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no 'IN()' support till realm version 1.1.0 but here some work around for 'IN()'

```
RealmQuery<YourObject> query = realm.where(YourObject.class);
for (String id : ids) {
  query.or().equalTo("yourField", id);
}
RealmResults<YourObject> results = query.findAll();
```