# Realm: Syntax error in query with beginGroup() and endGroup()

Tags: java, android, realm

I am getting a crash due to a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Syntax error` while executing such query:

```
public RealmResults<MyObject> getMyObjects(List<Integer> ids, boolean filter) {
    Realm realm = null;
    try {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmQuery<MyObject> query = realm.where(MyObject.class);
        query = query.beginGroup();
        for (int i=0; i< ids.size(); i++) {
            query = query.equalTo("id", ids.get(i));
            if (i != ids.size() -1) {
                query = query.or();
            }
        }
        query = query.endGroup();
        if (filter) {
            query = query.equalTo("someBoolean", true);
        }
        return query.findAll();
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) realm.close();
    }
}
```

Removing the `query = query.beginGroup();` and `query = query.endGroup();` makes the syntax error go away but I'm not sure if the query will yield the same results.

Can somebody help me pointing out where the syntax error is and why it happens?

Comment: There is no further information about the error in the log, all I get is `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Syntax error`

Comment: You might wish to use https://realm.io/docs/java/1.2.0/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#in-java.lang.String-java.lang.Long:A-

Comment: What does `ids.size()` return?

Comment: Its the size of the input array, which must not be null. So that won't cause the crash.
I use that if to append as many ORs I need except for the last element in the chain or i'll end up with a lone OR at the end of the query.

Comment: Wow didn't know about the in() query method. It works indeed!
But I still can't explain why the syntax error though.

Comment: We introduced `in()` recently. It would be great if you can create a small example (or unit test) and a Github issue so we can see if there is a bug.

Comment: @geisshirt I've tried to reproduce the bug in a small project but I couldn't: the query reported above now executes fine. It could have been a PBKAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `in()` operator that was added in 1.2.0.

Previously I would have just told you to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32068221/2413303)